# deserializing xml file from xstream

Tags: java, deserialization, xstream

I am using Xstream to serializing a Job object. It looks working fine.

but deserializing, I have a problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not . (position: START_DOCUMENT seen .... @1:1) 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:137)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:130)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:94)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:48)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver.createReader(XppDriver.java:44)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:845)
```

Did one of you get this problem before?

This is the way, I did for serializing:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();                    
Writer writer = new FileWriter(new File("model.xml"));
writer.write(xstream.toXML(myModel));
writer.close();
```

I also try this as well:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();                    
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("model.xml");
xstream.toXML(myModel, out);
```

For deserializing, I did it like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();

xstream.fromXML("model.xml");
```

XML structure:

```
<projectCar.CarImpl> 
   <CarModel reference="../.."></CarModel>
</projectCar.CarImpl>
```

If yes, I would like to hear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. But if you'd include the XML, or at least the first couple of lines of it, I might be able to help.

Comment: How's your XML document looks like, at least the beginning?

Comment: <projectCar.CarImpl>
  <name>CarModel</name> This is the first lines of my xml.

Comment: this is the way I did for serializing: XStream xstream = new XStream();     
Writer writer = new FileWriter(new File("model.xml"));
writer.write(xstream.toXML(myModel));
writer.close();

Comment: @JoesyXHN, it would appear that `<projectCar.CarImpl>` is not a valid tag due to the `.`. Can we see the rest of your XML document? Posting the Java code will not help us in this situation.

Comment: but in Java, a sub package is always: packageMain.PackageChild, so any idea to solve this? thank in advance

Comment: I think you should try simply `xstream.toXMl( myModel, writer );`, otherwise you can have encoding problems, which may cause this. And `flush()` the writer before closing it, jsut to be on the safe side.

Comment: I also tried it but it does not work as well :(

Comment: How are you deserializing the XML? Can you include that code as well because it may be serializing fine, but you may not be deserializing correctly.

Comment: For deserializing, I updated my implementation above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also include your XML file in the question?

Comment: hi all, I think the problem in my XML: I have: reference="../.." but I cant replace it using: xstream.aliasAttribute("twoSpaces", "../../.."); it does not work

Comment: try a different value for 'reference' and see if it works

Comment: I tried all! any other serialization tool for java perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fromXML does not take a filename, try:

```
File xmlFile = new File("model.xml");
xstream.fromXML(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
```

to read the file contents as a String.

Also the fieldnames 'id' and 'reference' happen to be 'system attributes' in XStream. Using the following code:

```
CarImpl myModel = new CarImpl();

File xmlFile = new File("model.xml");

XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.useAttributeFor(String.class);
xstream.useAttributeFor(Integer.class);

Writer writer = new FileWriter(xmlFile);        
writer.write(xstream.toXML(myModel));
writer.close();

CarImpl fromXML = (CarImpl) xstream.fromXML(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
System.out.println(fromXML);
```

unmarshalling fails if the fields are called 'id' and 'reference', but succeeds otherwise. See [XStream FAQ](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization_system_attributes)

Take a look at the new method 'aliasForSystemAttribute' for a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. The same problem after deserializing: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not "."

Comment: Could it be the file cannot be found? Make sure you write the serialized XML to the same file that you try to read it from.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your model classes? Did you use annotations to alias the attributes, or did you do it via useAttributeFor calls?

Comment: no, serializing to XMl is OK. but deserializing is a problem. I can not provide the code of my model classes. it is in a java library, I can only get the implement class.

Comment: @Joesy: My money is on a byte-order mark in the top-of-file, although I don't see how a BOM translates to a period. So... Forget your other SOF-question and just download a Hex editor. There's plenty of good free ones (google it). I use one called NEO, but it's "nothing special". Cheers. Keith.

Comment: @JoeseyXHN Well I'm still curious how the fields 'id' and 'reference' end up as attributes in your XML. This is not default behavior for XStream.

Comment: @Adriaan, I made a mistake: ID is not there, only reference with weird value is there.

Comment: You can download JD-GUI from http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui and decompile the class file. Then we will now exactly what's inside. This will only take you about 3 minutes.